# How do I share my React Native application with others which runs on Expo Go?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, expo

I have made an app using **React Native** which runs on **Expo Go (on iOS)**. The app functions pretty well. To run the app, I have to open VS Code and get a **QR code**. Is there any other way in which I can run the app? It would be great if someone could tell me a way to **share the app** with others or a way to run the app without using my PC.

Comment: No, you have to build it and upload to the AppStore.
If you don't use native modules (like camera), you could build it as webapp and upload to a CDN.